# JQUERY - after typing in textarea .change of select menu doesnt do anything

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am little bit confused of that what happened because it's illogical for me. What's the point?

I have such a HTML:

```
<select id="id_number">
    <option value="0">option 1</option>
    <option value="1">option 2</option>
    <option value="2">option 3</option>

</select>
<br /><br />
<textarea id="description" placeholder="whatever">test1</textarea>
```

and such jquery

```
$("#id_number").change(function() {
    $("#description").text('123');  // test function
});
```

When I load the page i should have select menu with 3 options and textarea with 'test1' text inside. And i do have. Now, when i change to any option, textarea changes to '123 as intended with test function. Unfortunatelly when I type any text in textarea from my keyboard, and again choose option from menu it is not putting '123' to textarea - i do not know why but nothing happens as if typing anything in textarea changed in some way state of textarea and jquery could change it anymore. Do you have any ideas how to change textarea text each time i change option in select menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text()` just change the value of the DOM element, the text area in this case, but it doesn't change the actual value. In order to do that, you have to use `val()`. You can find more information about it on the jQuery documentation page: http://api.jquery.com/text/.

Comment: Thank you for that answer - it was helpful because it now works as I intended. Unfortunately I read that textarea "doesnt have value" like other input tags and i have to change 'html' or 'text'. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose that it is a problem with where you have your jQuery statement in the HTML itself. Cause the code works for me on JSFiddle... Look here http://jsfiddle.net/AKuWd/

However, when you change to "nowrap (body)" it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this for select any option:

$('#id_number').live('change', function(){

```
var id_number_value=$('#id_number').val(); 
$('#description').val('');
var description_value=$('#description').val();
if(id_number_value=='' || id_number_value=='null')
    $('#description').val(id_number_value+""+description_value);
else 
    $('#description').val(id_number_value+" ");
```

});